# looking for fat32 source

Tags: c++, c, linux, fat32

I am looking for open source code for implementing fat32 in C or C++.I thought It would be easy to find several online but it appears to be evading me. I don't have a problem with GPL or any other open source license.

Comment: A simple google search returns quite a few options on page 1: https://www.google.com/search?q=fat32+source

Comment: Maybe narrowing down to a particular OS would give you even better search results. E.g. googling for 'freertos fat32' gives a number of promising results.

Comment: Additionally note that the problem might not be GPL, but M$ patented extras!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at `fs/fat` directory in the Linux kernel [sources](https://www.kernel.org/) for a Linux implementation.